# Alternatives for <X> in <Country>

Tags: discussion

I would like < X > service in my country as well but with 195 Countries what do we with these questions ?

Comment: I was just considering this.  I saw a mint.com tag, so I added those to the couple that didn't have it.  I think the question would be better is a general "Alternatives for <X> in <Country>".  http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1562/are-there-any-good-pandora-alternatives-with-general-availability-outside-the-us .  While not individual-country-specific, I think it still applies.

Comment: @rchern - while I see where you're coming from a generic question like that can't have one "correct" answer as there'll (probably) be a different answer for each country.

Comment: Oh, I meant on the Meta side, we should discuss how to handle country alternatives in general rather than just for Mint.com

Comment: Updated the question title and body

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe we could round them all up in a single community edited "Mint alternatives" or "Financial applications" where we could list which application works where.

Then whenever such questions appear, we can just point them there and close the question.

Comment: Hmm, not sure after reading http://meta.webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/73/what-are-some-sites-or-lets-make-a-list-of-x-type-questions/76#76

Comment: I think this is the way to go as I saw Jeff the other day merging these questions

Comment: @phwd I think it would help tidy up things, should we create a community wiki for "Mint alternatives" or for "Financial applications"? The question would list each alternative (alphabetically I'd say) and they would link to a single answer each. Each answer would contain the name of the alternative, a few features and a list of countries it works for. Sounds good?

Comment: sounds good to me.

Answer (score 3):

Shut them all down as "too localized" since they are very much localised only to those certain regions of the globe.

We should be looking to be a great place to find answers on web app problems. Not another generic links directory and pseudo-blog for top ten lists.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer one version of the question where it's just: What's an alternative to X?

Then the countries that are supported should be mentioned (if it's limited) or a link should be provided so that others can find out if the site is also for them.

But please STOP all the questions for each individual country!

Comment: Note to self: make sure my own questions comply!

Comment: Going even further, what about: Alternative ____ (web app types)
Eg: Alternative web apps for taking notes. Then those asking for alternatives to Evernote, Ubernote etc can all be directed to one page.